# Boolean Algebra: Simplefication, $(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC)(AC)' + (BD)(BD)'$

Tags: boolean-algebra

I want to know, how to prove this,

> $(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC)(AC)' + (BD)(BD)'.$

Please, help me.... Thanks.
What laws in that line?

Comment: We know that $xx' = 0$. Hence $(AC)(AC)' = 0$ and $(BD)(BD)' = 0$. Therefore the whole expresion equals $0$. Why do you need to simplify an expression which is equal to $0$?

Comment: Cuz, To prove it. I want to prove (AC+BD)(AC+BD)'=0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you are trying(as I understand from your comment) is to prove that $(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = 0$. We have:
$$(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC)(AC)'(BD)'+ (BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC)(AC)'(BD)' + (BD)(BD)'(AC)'$$

We know that $xx' = 0$. So $(AC)(AC)' = 0$ and $(BD)(BD)' = 0$. Therefore:
$$(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' =  (AC)(AC)'(BD)' + (BD)(BD)'(AC)' = 0 + 0 = 0$$

Another proof(by De Morgan's law):
$$(AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC + BD)(AC + BD)' = 0$$

Comment: Hmmm... Sorry for my Question. and Thank you.
But, In Solution. There is one more step.
=(AC+BD)(AC)'(BD)' 
=(AC)(AC)' + (BD)(BD)'
=((AC) + (AC)')' + ((BD) + (BD)')' 
So, I want to know that step.
I mean, What laws in that line. In second line.

Comment: I've done a typo mistake. I corrected it!

Comment: I checked it, But, I want to know how to prove my question.
I will accept you in few minutes later, But, can u check again?

Comment: Actually Full prove is here.
= (AC + BD)(AC)'(BD)' = (AC)(AC)' + (BD) (BD)'  = ((AC) + (AC)')' + ((BD) + (BD)')'  = (1)' + (1)'  = 0
I just want to know that line. Thanks

Comment: I cannot figure out how one can go for the first line to the second. Maybe it's a mistake. I dont't think that there is a law that allows such an operation. But I provided an alternative proof that is quicker that the first one I showed. I apologise if I could't help you!

Comment: OK, Thank you. Have a niceday!